# Magento 2.3.0 "A technical problem with the server created an error." When uploading the logo image

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, magento2.3, magento2.3.0, php-7.2

I'm using Magento 2.3.0, with php 7.2 version, on a ubuntu os.
Everything looks working fine, but when I try to go into Magento backend, Content - Design/Configuration - Header, and I try to upload the logo image, I get this:

```
A technical problem with the server created an error. Try again to continue what you were doing. If the problem persists, try again later.
```

I have tried already to change the user password, to check the index.php for any echo code, tried also to upgrade, compile, deploy, reindex, clean cache, but nothing, I still get this error..

Comment: Check your logs and post the relevant part here.

Comment: That's the thing.. there is no relevant part.. checked logs, exceptions.. the image actually gets uploaded on the server if I check the folder, but it get's that error anyway in the backend, and shows no image..

Comment: @alexcr What OS you are using Windows or any Linux?

Comment: @zus ubuntu os, so linux!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There is a bug in the Magento 2.3 version, but you can resolve the issue by making changes in the following code.

Navigate to the file located at: `/vendor/magento/module-theme/view/adminhtml/ui_component/design_config_form.xml` and replace the occurrence of **"fileUploader"** with **"imageUploader"** This adjustment will address the problem.

Please see below for more information.

```
    <collapsible>true</collapsible>
                <label translate="true">HTML Head</label>
            </settings>
            <!-- Remove this code -->
            <!-- <field name="head_shortcut_icon" formElement="fileUploader">-->
           
            <!-- Add this code -->
            <field name="head_shortcut_icon" formElement="imageUploader">
                <settings>
                    <notice translate="true">Not all browsers support all these formats!</notice>
                    <label translate="true">Favicon Icon</label>

                <collapsible>true</collapsible>
                <label translate="true">Header</label>
            </settings>
            <!-- Remove this code -->
            <!-- <field name="header_logo_src" formElement="fileUploader"> -->

            <!-- Add this code -->
            <field name="header_logo_src" formElement="imageUploader">
                <settings>
                    <label translate="true">Logo Image</label>
                    <componentType>imageUploader</componentType>
```

Please check and let me know in case of any issue.

Comment: editing core files is not a good idea. You can apply the fix via composer patching. ref: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/256668/magento-2-3-0-transactional-email-logo-image-upload-not-working

Comment: @ProxiBlue this is the magento bug and the issue has already fixed in 2.3-develop branch and will be available on 2.3.1 release, so no matter if we edit core files in this case.

Comment: @ProxiBlue please check this url for more information about magento bug : https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/19872

Comment: Can you please help me to solve this [issue](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/262077/how-to-add-a-date-picker-recursively-in-magento2-admin-form) @Aasim Goriya

Comment: Just in case someone comes across this post b/c they got the technical error message when trying to upload a logo image for the transaction emails, you have to change "fileUploader" to "imageUploader" in vendor/magento/module-email/view/adminhtml/ui_component/design_config_form.xml.  See @user2240778 answer for more info here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/256668/magento-2-3-0-transactional-email-logo-image-upload-not-working

Answer (score 6):

This is a Magento 2.3 bug, added wrong value for `formElement` for field `header_logo_src`

You can go to the file `vendor/magento/module-theme/view/adminhtml/ui_component/design_config_form.xml`

and in line number 154 you can see `<field name="header_logo_src" formElement="fileUploader">` this you can change with `<field name="header_logo_src" formElement="imageUploader">`

But editing Magento core is not a good idea, for temporary fix till Magento release the patch you can use the following module I created just to rewrite `design_config_form.xml`

https://github.com/arshadpkm/magento-2.3-header-logo-upload-bug-fix

Comment: Can you please add instructions? I have no idea how to use that repo.
Is installing via composer sufficient, or do I need to take extra steps?

Answer (score 2):

Assign permission to them,

Please Follow this link: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/10071

Comment: What do you mean with permission, for the admin role? the "role resources"? I have alread assigned all to the user, and it still get this error.. maeby any permission to any folder.. any 777 folder?

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in Magento 2.3. It will be fixed in the upcoming 2.3.1 release. Please refer to this link:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/18688

Answer (score 1):

The error message "A technical problem with the server created an error. Try again to continue what you were doing. If the problem persists, try again later." plus the popup "A problem occurred" on Magento 2 back-end is related to rewrite issues according to my logs and it was fixed by correctly configuring the server.
If you run this on nginx server please check if you have the configuration file that comes with Magento default on the webroot/nginx.conf.sample is copied/renamed and included in your nginx configuration and has the below block:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to increase the memory_limit in your .htaccess file in magento folder.