# Magento 2.3 Can't upload logo

Tags: magento2.3, upload, logo

Duplicate

Context: I've read all the similar questions (tried all the chmod stuff) and tried looking at magento logs, but there isn't anything that gets rid of this.

Seems like there is a error somewhere that is stopping us from creating the uploaded image.

Error Message:

```
A technical problem with the server created an error. Try again to continue what you were doing. If the problem persists, try again later.
```

Magento Logs:

```
Nothing
```

Apache Logs:

```
AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/html/app/etc/config.php
```

[image: Admin Console Action]

[image: Admin console error]
[image: Apache Log]

Comment: please can anyone here help me upload my logo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Magento 2.3.0 "A technical problem with the server created an error." When uploading the logo image](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/252276/magento-2-3-0-a-technical-problem-with-the-server-created-an-error-when-uploa)

@Aasim Goriya

```
Go to this file : /vendor/magento/module-theme/view/adminhtml/ui_component/design_config_form.xml and please remove "fileUploader" and add "imageUploader".
```