# Magento 2.3.0 unable to insert images in tinymce content

Tags: magento2, image, media, magento2.3.0, tinymce

I notice that I couldn't **insert images** when adding products in **tinymce content part**.
When I click on **Insert Image button**, I saw error as image below
I granted access to `/media directory 777`.

I followed the instruction [Magento 2.3.0 "A technical problem with the server created an error." When uploading the logo image](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/252276/magento-2-3-0-a-technical-problem-with-the-server-created-an-error-when-uploa) but it did not fix issue. I checked  `var/log/system.log` but the log did not show any text errors.

[image]

Comment: i am also facing the same issue, can you please share the solution urgently for the same.