# uploading favicon results in error on Magento2.3?

Tags: magento2, design, magento2.3, favicons

When I try to upload a new icon, it fails with this error.  Same with uploading logo image.  How do I debug this further?

```
A technical problem with the server created an error. Try again to continue what you were doing. If the problem persists, try again later.
```

[update]
This is bug in magento 2.3 please check this question answer I’m sure it will help you [Magento 2.3.0 "A technical problem with the server created an error." When uploading the logo image](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/252276/magento-2-3-0-a-technical-problem-with-the-server-created-an-error-when-uploa?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in Magento 2.3 that causes this issue.  Follow this post to fix it.

[Magento 2.3.0 "A technical problem with the server created an error." When uploading the logo image](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/252276/magento-2-3-0-a-technical-problem-with-the-server-created-an-error-when-uploa?rq=1)

Comment: The linked resource fixes the issue by editing core files. It is not a good idea. You can fix this with composer patching: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/256668/magento-2-3-0-transactional-email-logo-image-upload-not-working

Comment: If you want to provide a different better answer, I can use it to mark it as resolved.

Comment: Hi. The link provided in my comment is the proper answer. These questions are duplicates, and should really be closed. However, someone downvoted my answer, without explanation or reasoning.