# Issue in saving Category images in fresh installed Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, category-image

I'm facing issue in saving category Images in default setup of Magento 2.3.

I've not made any customization and didn't install any custom extension. I got this error:

> A technical problem with the server created an error. Try again to continue what you were doing. If the problem persists, try again later.

Kindly help me.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/252276/magento-2-3-0-a-technical-problem-with-the-server-created-an-error-when-uploa

Comment: I didn't found anything useful there.

Comment: Do you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

```
step (1)  can you change admin user password

step (2)  Admin > System > Index Management  and also re-indexing. 

then  let me know. thanks
```

Comment: Same error again!

Comment: A technical problem with the server created an error. Try again to continue what you were doing. If the problem persists, try again later.

Comment: jquery.js:10254 POST https://173.249.156.189/migdev1/admin_1sijyj/catalog/category/validate/key/87b17bd1974b69048a926c203e28e245a3f60f2ada54337cb82242d69a7894f0/?isAjax=true 403 (Forbidden)
send @ jquery.js:10254
ajax @ jquery.js:9738
beforeSave @ client.js:35
save @ client.js:91
save @ provider.js:62
submit @ form.js:313
save @ form.js:265
dispatch @ jquery.js:5226
elemData.handle @ jquery.js:4878

Comment: Do you have any suggestions?