# Magento 2.3.0 Logo upload failed

Tags: magento2.3, logo

Preconditions (*)

```
Magento 2.3.x
```

Steps to reproduce (*)

```
Content -> Design -> Configuration
Edit any Default Store View
Other Settings -> Header
Upload a favicon or logo
```

Expected result (*)

```
Favicon or logo is uploaded and "filled in the form"
```

Actual result (*)

```
Error message :" A technical problem with the server created an error. Try again to continue what you were doing. If the problem persists, try again later."
image
```

This issue has been tackled multiple times on Github and here. However, I tried the suggested fixes
(
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/18688
[Magento 2.3.0 "A technical problem with the server created an error." When uploading the logo image](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/252276/magento-2-3-0-a-technical-problem-with-the-server-created-an-error-when-uploa)
)
and this issue still persists for me.

Last entry in the system.log:
[2021-01-14 13:50:34] main.WARNING: Failed to retrieve the release notification content. The response is: Response body is empty. [] []

Comment: Have you check your error log?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya I've editted the question and added the only row that matches the time stamp of when I was uploading the image

Comment: Issue has been fixed, it appears to have been a cache issue. The suggested fix was the solution. Can an admin please close this issue