# After login the admin panel we find this error

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, admin-panel

**After login the admin panel we find this error .**

A technical problem with the server created an error. Try again to continue what you were doing. If the problem persists, try again later.

How to fix it ??

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is the bug in the Magento 2.3 version.

You can try this solution : [https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/252276/magento-2-3-0-a-technical-problem-with-the-server-created-an-error-when-uploa#:~:text=This%20is%20the%20bug%20in%20the%20Magento%202.3%20version%2C%20but%20you%20can%20fix%20the%20issue%20by%20the%20change%20in%20the%20below%20code](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/252276/magento-2-3-0-a-technical-problem-with-the-server-created-an-error-when-uploa#:%7E:text=This%20is%20the%20bug%20in%20the%20Magento%202.3%20version%2C%20but%20you%20can%20fix%20the%20issue%20by%20the%20change%20in%20the%20below%20code).

Comment: thank you quickshiftin

Comment: Anytime! Happy Coding :)